# What are most common formulas for computing inequality?

Tags: political-theory, political-system, economy, inequality, poverty

For the moment let's ignore distribution models like meritocracy.  Suppose a group has decided to divide their money in a certain way.  What are the different formulas to measure how even or equal their division is, (irrespective of their personal needs, efforts, etc.), strictly mathematically speaking?

For instance, we could calculate an *"index of inequality"* as:

- the sum of all the differences in the incomes of people,
- Or  as the sum of all differences from the average.
- Or from the median.

In short, there are many ways such an index might be defined, which affects how big a priority it is for the group.  What are the main approaches of measuring economic inequality?

Comment: I think it is more of an statistical question (standard deviation, varianza, etc.)

Comment: As stated, this seems more appropriate on statistics SE.

Comment: @SJuan78 I think sociology would be the most appropriate, the question seems too subjective to me to be migrated on statistics in its current form.

Comment: Equality only has one meaning in math. It has infinite meanings in politics. I don't think this question makes sense.

Comment: @blip The state of total equality has only one meaning in math. But just how I've said, the degree of equality (what is more and what is less equal) can be measured in many ways. Considering your comment, I really don't understand how this question could be too broad but I've realized that it could be suitable for philosophy much better.

Comment: Please clarify if the division of the group's money is to be a *one-time* instance, or a periodical payment.  It's also unclear whether the measurement of inequality should be based on the receivers periodic [incomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income), or their pre-division [assets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asset).

Comment: @agc For the sake of simplicity, let's assume it's one time instance and everybody gets equal incomes and assets.

Comment: @Probably, given the standard usage of the term *"asset"*, then a *"one time instance and everybody gets equal incomes and **assets**."* would result in a numeric leveling, (i.e. no inequality, for most any circumstance-blind formula).  Perhaps you meant to use a different term, such as "fixed sum".

Comment: This has perfectly reasonable and easy answers. The most common index is the Gini index, followed by comparing the incomes at various percentiles.

Comment: I've moved the question on [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/what-are-most-common-formulas-for-computing-inequality)